# Iterating through matrix rows in Octave without using an index or for loop

Tags: octave, vectorization

I am trying to understand if it's possible to use Octave more efficiently by removing the for loop I'm using to calculate a formula on each row of a matrix X:

```
myscalar = 0
for i = 1:size(X, 1),
  myscalar += X(i, :) * y(i) % y is a vector of dimension size(X, 1)
  ...
```

The formula is more complicate than adding to a scalar. The question here is really how to iterate through X rows without an index, so that I can eliminate the for loop.

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to be doing. On each loop it simply multiplies a vector `X(i,:)` by a scalar `y(i)`. Your `myscalar` is actually a vector. Unless X has only a single column but then why are setting it? And why are you transposing for the multiplication? Also, there is no need to use `size (X, 1)`, Octave already has the functions `rows` and `columns` exactly for this purposes.

Comment: My question is really about that for loop, not any code in particular. True, the transpose is confusing, so I'm going to fix it, but is there a way to remove the indexing and the for loop?

Comment: probably yes but I can't tell you how because the code makes no sense. Is `myscalar` supposed to be a scalar? A sum of multiplications? A matrix? Of what size? I don't understand what you want.

Comment: ok, I fixed myscalar but I don't understand why it is so important to focus on the code. This is a general question, is there a way to avoid matrix indexing when applying formulas on each row, or column, rather than each element (in which case vectorization is more obvious)?

Comment: now makes sense. I was not understand what was happening to `myscalar` because you were simply overwriting over it before, not adding to it (`=` instead of `+=`).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use [broadcasting](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html#Broadcasting) for this (you will need 3.6.0 or later). If you know python, this is the same ([an explanation from python](http://memory.osu.edu/classes/python/lessons/lsn08.html)). Simply multiply the matrix by the column. Finnaly, `cumsum` does the addition but we only want the last row.

```
newx      = X .* y;
myscalars = cumsum (newx, 1) (end,:);
```

or in one line without temp variables

```
myscalars = cumsum (X .* y, 1) (end,:);
```

If the sizes are right, broadcasting is automatically performed. For example:

```
octave> a = [ 1 2 3
              1 2 3
              1 2 3];
octave> b = [ 1 0 2];
octave> a .* b'
warning: product: automatic broadcasting operation applied
ans =

   1   0   6
   1   0   6
   1   0   6

octave> a .* b
warning: product: automatic broadcasting operation applied
ans =

   1   2   3
   0   0   0
   2   4   6
```

The reason for the warning is that it's a new feature that may confuse users and is not existent in Matlab. You can turn it off permanentely by adding `warning ("off", "Octave:broadcast")` to your `.octaverc` file

For anyone using an older version of Octave, the same can be accomplished by calling `bsxfun` directly.

```
myscalars = cumsum (bsxfun (@times, X, y), 1) (end,:);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do same thing in Octave under 3.6 version, may be (2.4)?

Comment: @Kaha there is no 2.4 version (version 2.0.16 was followed by 2.9.14). But this can also be done as long as the `bsxfun` is implemented. I have edited my answer to show alternative for older versions.